# Creating a DatePeriod array with future dates using CArbon

Tags: php, arrays, database, date, php-carbon

I have an `Courses` model that contains a `start_date` column back in my DB. From this `start_date` I want to generate an array of the next 6 weeks for that day of the week.

e.g., If the `start_date` is Monday, December 4th, 2017, I want to generate an array with the next 6 preceding Mondays, where the array also includes the original `start_date` as well as the 6th date.

Heres the logic Ive attempted in my model:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;

class Product {




    public function getRange($date) {
      return new \DatePeriod(
        Carbon::parse($date),
        CarbonInterval::week(),
        Carbon::parse($date)->addWeeks(6)
      );
    }

}
```

However when i try outputting this in my template i get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Object of class DatePeriod could not be converted to string").

suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late. But when I was reviewing this answer, I noticed that it did not match with what you were asking.

The problem that is causing your `Exception` is probably because the `DateRange` is not handled correctly in your view file. You'll need to loop through your range of dates and output each of the date by using the `format``method.

Here's an example on how to do this:

```
<?php foreach($product->getRange(new DateTime()) as $date): ?>
    <?= $date->format("Y-m-d"); ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```